# subtract a different vector from each row in a matrix in r

Tags: r

I'm using R.
These are my data:

- `Prot_before`: A matrix with 70000 rows and, each row has two columns:
  group (There are 700 groups) and value per sample (There are 120
  samples).
- `Prot_healthy`: A matrix with 30000 rows and, each row has two columns:
  group (There are 700 groups) and value per sample (There are 45
  samples).

For each row in `prot_before`, I want to find its value minus the values for all samples in that group in `prot_healthy`.

For example:

```
set.seed(100) 
Prot_before <- data.frame(cat = c(rep("aaa", 5), rep("bbb", 5), rep("ccc", 5)), val = runif(15))             
Prot_before <- df[order(df$cat, df$val), ]  
Prot_before
```

```
set.seed(100) 
Prot_after <- data.frame(cat = c(rep("aaa", 5), rep("bbb", 5), rep("ccc", 5)), val = runif(15))             
Prot_after <- df[order(df$cat, df$val), ]  
Prot_after
```

Now I want the results of each row in prot_before, minus all the samples in the same group `aaa` etc, in `prot_after`. So for each row in `prot_before` I get 45 results.
I tried using sweep but didn't know how the repeat the function for all samples by group.

I'm sorry if this isn't written correctly, I'm not very experienced.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide expected result?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `split` by 'cat' for each dataset into a `list`, and then use `outer` to do the subtraction for all the combination rows for corresponding `list` elements using `Map`

```
Map(outer, MoreArgs = list(FUN = `-`), 
    split(Prot_before$val, Prot_before$cat), split(Prot_after$val, Prot_after$cat))
```

Or with `sapply` and `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) sapply(x, `-`, y),  
   split(Prot_before$val, Prot_before$cat), split(Prot_after$val, Prot_after$cat))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` row-wise, subset `cat` from `Prot_after` and subtract all the corresponding `val` values

```
apply(Prot_before, 1, function(x) {
   as.numeric(x["val"]) - Prot_after$val[Prot_after$cat == x["cat"]]
})
```